# How to start loading javascript code asynchronously before the window load event without blocking window.load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, page-load-time

I'm trying to load some javascript code asynchronously during page load, but I don't want to hold up the window.load event, so window.load should fire even if the async script is not loaded yet.

I tried using `<script async src="...">`, but it's no good, because window.load fires when all the linked scripts are loaded, so although async scripts are loaded asynchronously, they are executed before window.load.

I use jquery, so also tried adding a document ready handler and load the script from there asynchronously with an ajax call, but according to chrome dev tools window.load still waits for this script, even if it's ajax call. (Can someone explain why?)

Is there an other method I could try?

Comment: What do you need `window.onload` for? What's wrong with deferring it - you after all *are* still loading ressorces?

Comment: @Bergi it's added to the page load time if window.load waits for it and I want to keep load time low, but I'd like to start it loading earlier than window.load, so it's available sooner, but it's not essential, so I don't want to delay window.load with that.  Do you have an idea why window.load waits for a script loaded with ajax? That's what I don't get. It should be completely asynchronous with window.load.

Comment: "page load time" is meaningless unless you precisely define it. Defining it in terms of the `load` event is pretty useless imo.

Comment: @Bergi  google uses the window.load event when determining page load time (that's what I see in analytics) and google likes it when a page loads quickly, that's why I don't want to increase page load time (as seen by google) with this script.

Comment: Well if you want to optimise for that, load an empty page with nothing but an inline script that waits for `window.onload` and then begins injecting all the assets that the user needs. Then ask yourself whether you want to make your users or Google more happy.

Comment: @Bergi  I'd like both. Keep load time low while loading some assets completely asynchronously without affecting window.load. It should be possible somehow.